# Google Maps - Wordpress Remove Speech Bubble

Tags: wordpress, google-maps

I am inserting the iFrame code from Googlemaps into a Wordpress Page.

What I would like to do is remove the address info bubble from the parameters, If possible?

My iFrame Code is :

```
<iframe width="610" height="180" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://www.google.co.uk/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=York,+YO61+1EY,+UK&amp;aq=0&amp;sll=53.800651,-4.064941&amp;sspn=19.563564,39.506836&amp;vpsrc=6&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=York+YO61+1EY,+United+Kingdom&amp;t=m&amp;ll=54.072182,-1.088762&amp;spn=0.017627,0.036478&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

Any help on this one appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All you need to do is add this into your iframe code

```
&iwloc=near
```

So replace your code with this

```
<iframe width="610" height="180" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://www.google.co.uk/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=York,+YO61+1EY,+UK&amp;aq=0&amp;sll=53.800651,-4.064941&amp;sspn=19.563564,39.506836&amp;vpsrc=6&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=York+YO61+1EY,+United+Kingdom&amp;t=m&amp;ll=54.072182,-1.088762&amp;spn=0.017627,0.036478&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed&amp;iwloc=near"></iframe>
```

Comment: No worries, could you accept this as the answer if it's right? Thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiousity @SpaceBeers is there a reference to these params?

Comment: Not sure about an official one but try here - http://querystring.org/google-maps-query-string-parameters/

Comment: @SpaceBeers - That link to the parameters for Google maps is now obsolete. I've found an alternative but added it to pastebin as a contigency: http://pastebin.com/phRJduUQ

Answer (score 1):

An even easier way than the above answer: just remove the capital A at the end of the iwloc code so it reads: iwloc=&